azure logic app local function - binding redirects
Following this doc I have an azure logic app standard with a .Net Framework (472) local function. This works ok until I add external dependencies such as service bus an identity, then start to hit problems with clashes of assembly versions.
The csproj file for my local function is as follows:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <!-- Please replace 'LogicAppFolder' with the name of your folder that contains your logic app project. -->
    <LogicAppFolder>LogicApp</LogicAppFolder>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
 </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.17.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core" Version="3.0.41" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Workflows.WebJobs.Sdk" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.4.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Task" AfterTargets="Compile">
    <ItemGroup>
        <DirsToClean2 Include="..\$(LogicAppFolder)\lib\custom" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <RemoveDir Directories="@(DirsToClean2)" />
 </Target>
 
  <Target Name="CopyExtensionFiles" AfterTargets="ParameterizedFunctionJsonGenerator">
    <ItemGroup>
        <CopyFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\bin\$(Configuration)\net472\**\*.*" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" Exclude="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\bin\$(Configuration)\net472\*.*" />
      <CopyFiles2 Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\bin\$(Configuration)\net472\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(CopyFiles)" DestinationFolder="..\$(LogicAppFolder)\lib\custom\%(RecursiveDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(CopyFiles2)" DestinationFolder="..\$(LogicAppFolder)\lib\custom\net472\" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
    <ItemGroup>
        <MoveFiles Include="..\$(LogicAppFolder)\lib\custom\bin\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>

   <Move SourceFiles="@(MoveFiles)" DestinationFolder="..\$(LogicAppFolder)\lib\custom\net472" />
    <ItemGroup>
       <DirsToClean Include="..\$(LogicAppFolder)\lib\custom\bin" />
     </ItemGroup>
       <RemoveDir Directories="@(DirsToClean)" />
  </Target>
 
  <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="bin\$(Configuration)\net472\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

The runtime exception is:
Result: Function 'ReadQueueSessionMessage', Invocation id '6eda05ec-d18d-41bf-832b-c02144b18cf7': An exception was thrown by the invocation.
Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.38.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
One way to solve this would be to use binding redirects but is that possible with a local function of a logic app? The only alternative I can think of is to tediously check each dependency of each referenced assembly but even then that doesn't overcome problem such as this: Azure.Identity BUG

Are you able to open the designer?

yes, why do you ask?

Did you find a resolution to this? I'm getting the exact same error using .net8

Hi Andrew, no answer I’m afraid. I’ve managed to work around by stripping down the nuget packages my local function uses to the bare minimum
